# Penises = rude and abusive?

Tags: discussion, community, deleted-answer

I was looking at this question
[Designing a low technology flamethrower with limited resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/211434/designing-a-low-technology-flamethrower-with-limited-resources)

and on a whim decided to see why an answer (deleted by "Community") was rude and abusive.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/211437/revisions

> Carve bones into a pump system, use a flab  of leather for the
> suction.
>
> Carve a leg bone into a hollow cane and use it to aim the fluid.  Melt
> fat from the dead bodies and use the oils as fuel.
>
> Use guts and penises as flexible tubes to move the fuel.
>
> Guts are longer and need to be treated to gain resistance, penises are
> shorter and more resistant but can be knitted together to make a
> longer tube.
>
> Use leather to make a bag for the fuel to sit in.
>
> Results will look like a flamethrowing bagpipe made from people.

This looks to be a straightforward on-point answer to the question of how to use dead body parts to make a thing.  It did not insult the poster or anyone else and did not digress into abusive irrelevancies.   The only way I can see that this might be considered rude and abusive is that penises (along with guts) were considered as working material.  Penises can be parts of dead bodies.

I think if this answer is rude and abusive then the whole concept of making things out of dead bodies is rude and abusive.  Or I am missing something - "Community" if you are there, unpack your reasoning?   Is "Community" a bot looking for forbidden words?

---

It was once not allowed to say "penis" on American TV.  When that rule was relaxed, Saturday Night Live celebrated with a [special song](https://youtu.be/G3xc4LMTrT0?t=165).

Comment: I'm really not into that kind of things, but sharing freedom is one of them, so I doubt I woke up midday and flagged that question with some account magic. That Komu Nitty must be less open to that kind of discussion :p.

Comment: The answer is solid, nothing wrong with it(except preservation aspect, guts are easier to preserve, I suggest use multilayered guts construction instead of penises). Yeah that demigan series of body positivity q's is questionable. I said to him under his first q use alternative word instead of body, suggested corpses(but not sure it a good replacement) as alien corpses carcasses are not bodies. So edgy topic, so no suprise it triggered someone or something. Try use that p word next time, will see how far your answer will slide, lol, doubt it a script - 127 result for word penis.

Comment: Community is a bot... and you know about the Stack Exchange Overlords' political leanings....

Comment: It's abusive of correct English and appropriate morphology, a penis wouldn't be much use as a pipe, a [prepuce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreskin) however would be the correct and appropriate word had they had both hands free to type a query into google.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. why it wouldnt be much use as a pipe?

Comment: Because it's full of tissues that would block the flow. You'd need to de-glove it and use the casing - which is called the prepuce. (I was just being silly and pedantic). @LiJun

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this post in the main Meta: [What causes a "Rude or offensive" comment flag to sometimes cause instant deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244439/221728)

It is now closed as a duplicate of [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/221728), which I find less clear.

Anyway, it seems that the presence of some words in comments and posts will cause automatic deletion once a rude/abusive flag is placed.

I do not think that the correct, anatomical term for a body part is necessarily dirty, it depends much on context. I think SE is trying to play it safe, thus the auto-deletion. I do not know whether undeleting the post will prevent it from being deleted again in the same manner. We could, however, edit it to use another term (male genital?) and then undelete.

Comment: Well, the answer in question was undeleted a couple days ago and has thus far remained free range in the wild.

Comment: Male genital not neccessrly correct, as gemigans creatures in q are all kinds of random ones, so god know which set of genitals they have. // @elemtilas funny, but now we lost the user, interesting

Comment: @MolbOrg -- Another random anonymous perhaps? A one answer wonder?

Comment: @elemtilas Judging by Tortliena comment it was some legit user Komu Nitty, at least it wasn't like that from the start. Could delete it on his own, buuutt that is the question actually. Self-deletion or deletion

Comment: @MolbOrg - I could be wrong, but am pretty sure "Komu Nitty" is a play on the pseudo-user name **Community**.

Comment: @elemtilas mm rigth, now I get it, lol, okay didn't got it initially, lol

Comment: The "seven dirty words" thing only applies to **comments, not posts**. Posts are never automatically deleted just for keywords they contain, no matter how abusive.

Answer (score 5):

Probably an over sensitive/over protective keyword bot.

Does Community respond to user flags? If so, then that might be part of it, if over sensitive people didn't like it and decided it needed to be removed for no actual good reason.

Comment: Well, we will see if it deletes this question then.

Comment: Do not think so, just to check it out, here https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161164/how-can-one-infect-shutdown-a-virtual-reality-game-using-technology was a spam answer today with an email(comment like joke), it now gone(flagged, as spam by me, maybe someone else did it too) so whos the user @Willk probably community

Comment: COmmunity does respond to flags.

Comment: Interesting that user account is now gone(as I understand), interesting the reason of deletion @Willk, 2all

Answer (score 5):

## That was probably not the reason

Looking at the activity log for the answer...

[image]

...we find that the user was removed from Stack Exchange a mere 13 minutes after posting the answer.

As far as I know, bots cannot remove people from Stack Exchange, so this appears to be a human intervention.

Considering the severity of the action, and the *lack* of offensive materials in the post, I find it safe to assume that the moderators based that action on information about the user that we are not privy to.

For these reasons — lack of offensive materials and user being removed from Stack Exchange — I find the assumption — to think that "penis" in the post was the sole reason the post got flagged — to be mistaken. To me, it seems obvious something else was going on, and that this user incurred the wrath of the moderators for something other (or more) than just this post.

Comment: okay, as expected - Cherchez la femme

Comment: While that might indeed be the reason, there's nothing safe in the assumption. Secret decisions are often corrupt decisions, and in the rare circumstance where they are not, they always encourage the appearance of such. SE deserves zero benefit of doubt. Individual people occasionally earn such privilege, organizations and companies never deserve it.

Comment: @JohnO Their house, their rules. Like it, or leave it.

Comment: @MichaelK Not a house, and if they want me to leave looks like they can kick me out. Me leaving voluntarily makes things worse, not better.

Comment: @JohnO Yes, their house. You are a guest in it and you stay at their leisure.

Comment: @MichaelK Not their house. A "house" carries the connotation that we're talking about actual real people, individuals or a small group, and that they have a right to guests behaving because it is their personal abode. Nothing so impersonal as a company has such a right. I am not a guest, I'm just a citizen wandering through a public space that they put up for the purpose of attracting customers. Others agree with me on these points, and we're not going to change our minds just because you tried to assert your opinion in an even louder voice.

Comment: @JohnO No, SE is not a "public space". It is privately owned, privately operated, and privately funded, and you are allowed into it upon agreeing to their rules, rules that — in case you have forgotten, or necer read them — say they can evict you for any reason they please. Very much a house.

Comment: @MichaelK It's very much a public space by any meaning of the term. Anyone from the public is allowed to enter and remain for any length of time. No attempt is made to check identities and exclude nonmembers. It's advertised as a public space and has been for years. Now you're at the point in your argument where because you've painted yourself into the corner, the only thing left to do is say "but black is white and dry is wet!" as if anyone should continue to listen to such nonsense. Grow up. People are allowed in even when not agreeing to the rules. Public spaces can be privately owned, etc.

Comment: @JohnO "Public spaces can be privately owned". Then you referencing this as "public space" means nothing, you just nullified that argument. SE is privately owned, privately operated, privately funded. The fact that they *let you* join it, does not change the fact that they let you join it on *their terms*... you know, that thing you clicked "I agree" on when *signing up*. That is why it is called "signing up", because you are doing just that: signing an agreement.

Comment: You argument : "like everything we do and never question it" its kinda like the same argument many nationalistic and dictatorship apologists say.

Comment: Plus, the mods are not private employees. Stackexhange as it advertises itself is nothing but a Q&A version of Wikipedia.com... pretty public to me.

Comment: @SteroidSandwich And do tell me how this entitles you to... well... anything, really.

Comment: Well, by your logic you are not entitled the very oxygen you are breathing right now. It was produced by forests and algae on land or sea you don't own.  Titles and rights are rarely earned, you are probably alive today because some of your ancestors were entitled and stubbord enough to slit the throat of those who tried to stomp them.

Comment: Plus just like wikipedia, this site is no content, WE ARE THE CONTENT.  A kingdom is just empty land without the people.

Comment: @SteroidSandwich *"Well, by your logic you are not entitled the very oxygen you are breathing right now. It was produced by forests and algae on land or sea you don't own."* No, that is not my logic, that is your claim and it makes absolutely no sense at all. *"Titles and rights are rarely earned,"* SE earned their site, by paying for it. And with that comes to right to allow you onto the site, on their terms. *"WE ARE THE CONTENT"* That entitles you to absolutely *nothing* and you are — despite that — subject of the Terms of Service and Code of Conduct on this site.